# RSA find $q$ given only $e$ and $p$

Tags: rsa

Lets say hypothetically all one knew was a value of $e$ and a value of $p$.

As an example, lets assume that $e = 13$ and $p = 67$.

Would it be possible to find the value of $q$ from this equation?

$\gcd(13, (66)(q-1)) = 1$

If so, how would I begin solving this?

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to $\gcd(13,q-1)=1$ in terms of constraints (not in value!)

Comment: is this a homework or CTF?

Comment: Might you actually intend to ask "how do I find $d$ such that $e \cdot d = 1 \pmod p$"?

Comment: This might have infinite solutions.

Comment: Well obviously you need $n$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RSA limiting down the possible values for $n,q$, and $d$? given only $e$ and $p$](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64579/rsa-limiting-down-the-possible-values-for-n-q-and-d-given-only-e-and-p)

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit strange.

Do you mean $n$ is unknown? Then there are infinitely many $q$ which will work. Since 13 and 66 are relatively prime, by @SEJPM's comment, all $q$ which are of the form
$$
q_k \neq 13k+1,
$$
are possible solutions. Depending on what $n$ you want you can take $k$ large enough. But in the RSA context $n$ must be public.