# RSA limiting down the possible values for $n,q$, and $d$? given only $e$ and $p$

Tags: encryption, rsa

Suppose someone forgot the value of $n$ and you only knew the values for $e$ and $p$. How could one go about limiting down the possible values for $n,q$, and $d$?

I'm thinking to try and solve $\gcd(e, (p-1)(q-1)) = 1$ first for possible values of q and work backward from there but I don't really know/

Comment: This question is curiously similar to https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64563/rsa-solve-equation asked a few hours ago under a different username.

Comment: Do you know a rule that was used in the choice of $p$ and $q$ (like, they both belong to $]2^{(k-1)/2},2^k[$ for some $k$ (which is very common)? Do you also have examples of ciphertext, or signature? A single RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signature and the matching message also allows to walk back to the full public and private key, given that $p$ is known.

Answer (score 1):

As there are an infinite number of prime numbers, and $q$ can be any prime number other than $p$ and which his not coprime with $e$, it would be literally impossible to limit the possible values to any finite number. That is, you could limit it to any possible $q$, of which there are infinity.

Comment: Commonly it should be that $|p|=|q|$, so you are limited to primes of length $|p|$ which makes the number finite. (Not that this actually helps.)

Comment: @Maeher It's still valid even if the sizes are different, even if it's uncommon.

Comment: Valid in what sense? Yes, the RSA TDP works fine with any choice of $p,q$ as long as both are prime and $p\neq q$, but $p$ and $q$ are always sampled from a finite set of prime numbers. It is impossible to efficiently sample uniformly from the infinite set of all prime numbers, so that would not be a viable option.

Comment: @Maeher Sure, but the question is about _possible_ values, not realistic values or values that you'll commonly find coming from OpenSSL. RSA itself would work even if one prime is one digit and the other is 8192-bits in size. It wouldn't be secure, of course, but it would be _possible_.